# How to see what /bin/sh points to

Tags: bash, shell, unix, aix

I was reading about the differences between /bin/sh and /bin/bash and came across this interesting question/answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash/5725402?noredirect=1#comment74080587_5725402)

I made a comment to the answer asking this same question in my title to which he replied with an updated answer:

> How can you find out what /bin/sh points to on your system?
>
> The complication is that /bin/sh could be a symbolic link or a hard
>   link. If it's a symbolic link, a portable way to resolve it is:

```
> % file -h /bin/sh
> /bin/sh: symbolic link to bash
```

> If it's a hard link,
>   try

```
> % find -L /bin -samefile /bin/sh 
> /bin/sh 
> /bin/bash
```

I tried this and had trouble so I thought I would make a separate question.

My results from the linked answer:

```
>file -h /bin/sh
>/bin/sh: executable (RISC System/6000) or object module

>find -L /bin -samefile /bin/sh
>find: bad option -samefile
```

What am I missing? 
I'm running AIX:

```
>oslevel -s
7100-03-03-1415
```

Comment: Run `man find`. It's a program that is very finnicky about options on different systems. Your version's `-samefile` will have a different name if it exists at all.

Comment: Looks like `/bin/sh` is indeed an executable on your system, not a symbolic link. Keep in mind that it is not necessarily "pointing to" some other shell executable. And apparently your `find` utility is not the gnu find utility and not compatible to that one. Which is not surprising for a commercial Unix variant.

Comment: @arkascha. The question is not if it's an executable vs a symlink at this point. The question is if it's a hard link to the bash executable.

Comment: I ran a search for "samefile" after running `man find` and returned no results.  So does this mean that my 'find' utility just doesn't support that flag?

Comment: AIX's `find` utility supports `-inum`. Get the `inode` from  `ls -i /bin/bash` then use `find /bin -inum inode` and see if `/bin/sh` will turn up. Or just compare the `inodes` of `ls -i /bin/sh /bin/bash`.

Comment: As with some other non-standard flags, -samefile is a convenience (like -delete) provided by GNU. There is a simple workaround:  to use the "inconvenient" version, often involving -exec. See my answer

Comment: @MadPhysicist I did understand that question quite well. But that first test the OP performed cannot distinguish between a hard link and a file, that is why the outcome of that test indicates a file. That is all I said.

Comment: Hard links are the filesystem pointer structures used for regular files.  The hard link is a reference to the inner data structures of the filesystem.  You cannot tell the difference between a regular file and a hard link, because all regular files are accessed through hard links.  A symbolic link is a file that contains a path, and this path is used to point to another file.  The data inside the symbolic link does not point to an inner data structure of the filesystem.  This is why a symbolic link can point to a separate filesystem, while a hard link cannot.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to programatically test if they are the same, you can use `stat` to query the `inode` of `/bin/sh` and compare with the `inode` of `/bin/bash`.

```
if [ $(stat -L -c %i /bin/sh) -eq $(stat -L -c %i /bin/bash) ]; then
    .....
fi
```

If you just need to see with your eyes if they are the same run the `stat` commands and see if they return the same `inode` number.

```
stat -L -c %i /bin/sh
stat -L -c %i /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are only searching through `bin` anyway, you can bypass `find` entirely and just check if `sh` and `bash` are hard links to the same file:

```
test /bin/sh -ef /bin/bash
```

OR

```
[ /bin/sh -ef /bin/bash ]
```

This is not as reliable as running `find` on all the possibilities, but it's a good start. While [AIX `find`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/find.htm) doesn't support `-samefile`, it does support `-exec`, which can be combined with the command above to simulate the same functionality:

```
find -L /bin -exec test /bin/sh -ef '{}' ';'
```

Comment: The best answer in my opinion when testing programatically.

Comment: Just a shortened notation for your answer, and I showed how to plug it into find.

Comment: All these years and I had never noticed the `-ef` operand to `test`. Thanks, TIL!

Answer (score 2):

### Check for GNU Bash

I'm going to answer your question in a different way, because it's actually simpler to find out if *sh* is GNU Bash (or something else that responds to a `--version` flag) than it is to chase inodes. **There's also the edge case where the shell is renamed rather than linked, in which case mapping links won't really help you find an answer.**

For example, to interrogate */bin/sh* on macOS:

```
$ /bin/sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Alternatively, you can grep (or similar) for the string `bash` to capture the exit status. For example:

```
# Close stderr in case sh doesn't have a version flag.
if sh --version 2>&- | grep -qF bash; then
  echo "sh is bash"
else
  echo "sh isn't bash"
fi
```

Of course, */bin/sh* could be some other shell besides bash or the original bourne shell, but that's outside the scope of your original question. However, many shells such as ksh and tcsh also support the version flag, so judicious use of a `case` statement could help you extend the test to determine exactly which shell binary */bin/sh* really is.

Answer (score 1):

As the answer you commented on says, `-samefile` isn't a standard feature of `find`. Neither is `-inum`, which searches based on an explicitly given inode number. But if your `find` supports that, use it.

POSIX `ls` supports `-i`, which prints the inode numbers. If `find` doesn't have `-inum`, all you need to do is go through all plausible files `/bin/sh` could be a hard link with...

Though before that, you could check if the file even has any other hard links, `ls -l` is required to show the number of links:

```
$ ls -l /bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1029624 Nov  5 23:22 /bin/bash
           ^ here
```

Of course, there's no requirement for `/bin/sh` to be linked to anything. It could be just another program. (Or even an identical copy of some of other file, though I don't think that's very likely.)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use :

```
ls -l /bin/sh
```

Comment: Hi, I think the question is a bit more complex than the solution you contributed. Consider expanding or removing.

Comment: How is this not complex enough? OP appears to be running a strange system for that to happen and he didn't really explain what was his confusion. This is exactly what I was looking for and it answers the question in the title if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do `readlink -f /bin/sh`. For me it points to `/bin/dash`.

Answer (score 0):

I can not really see the point of this exercise.

`/bin/sh` is a POSIX shell and `bash` has extensions to the POSIX standard that `/bin/sh` does not support.

If you are writing a POSIX shell script, use `/bin/sh`.  If you are writing a `bash` shell script, use `bash`.

Do not try to write a `bash` script that will be executed with `/bin/sh`, and don't try to programatically try to determine the abilities of the current shell based on what `/bin/sh` (or the current interpreter) is linked to.  Instead, make the script executable and use the correct `#!`-line for the script.

Answer (score 0):

On mac, you can just do `la /private/var/select`. The output would look something like this.

```
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     9B Aug 24  2022 sh -> /bin/bash
```